# How to customize invoice print odoo 10

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

i want to customize my invoice pdf printed paper to something different of what odoo provide, for example like this 
[image]

Comment: Yes, You can make your own PDF report in odoo.

Comment: But how, can you give me some advice please

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to modify existing report than inherit odoo repot. And
   change using **xpath** tag. Otherwise you also create your own report
   using xml tags.
   Example May useful for you :

Report menu button from Print Menu :

```
<report
   id="saleorder_quotation_report"
   model="account.invoice"
   string="Print Invoice"
   report_type="qweb-pdf"
   name="module_name.your_report_id"
   file="module_name.your_report_id"
   attachment_use="False"
   />
```

Here sample code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <template id="put_your_xml_id">
            <t t-call="module_name.external_layout">
                <t t-set="o" t-value="o.with_context({'lang':o.partner_id.lang})" />
                <div class="page">
                <div class="col-xs-6" style = "margin-top:15px;">
                    <strong>Invoicing address:</strong>
                    <div t-field="o.partner_id"
                        <!-- Here you make your own code using div and other tags -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </t>
        </template>
        <template id="your_report_id">
            <t t-call="report.html_container">
                <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
                    <t t-call="module_name.put_your_xml_id" t-lang="o.partner_id.lang"/>
                </t>
            </t>
       </template>
  </data>
```